# How can encode('ascii', 'ignore') throw a UnicodeDecodeError?

Tags: python, unicode-string

This line

```
data = get_url_contents(r[0]).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

produces this error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 11450: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Why? I assumed that because I'm using 'ignore' that it should be impossible to have decode errors when saving the output to a value to a string variable.

Comment: The problem is with _decoding_, not _encoding_. They're not the same.

Comment: Wt does `get_url_contents` do? This looks like the exception is raised in that function, not in `encode`.

Comment: @Trindaz, 0xc3 is not an ASCII character.

Comment: r[0] may be ASCII but the return from get_url_contents is not.

Comment: Please post a solution if you remember...

Comment: I have also the same problem. I just want to discard any unicode character.

Answer (score 3):

Due to a quirk of Python 2, you can call `encode` on a byte string (i.e. text that's already encoded). In this case, it first tries to convert it to a unicode object by decoding with ascii. So, if get_url_contents is returning a byte string, your line effectively does this:

```
get_url_contents(r[0]).decode('ascii').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

In Python 3, byte strings don't have an `encode` method, so the same problem would just cause an AttributeError.

(Of course, I don't know that this is the problem - it could be related to the `get_url_contents` function. But what I've described above is my best guess)