# Is there a way to ask numpy to ignore UnicodeEncode errors when creating ndarrays made up of text?

Tags: arrays, string, numpy

I am an absolute novice to Python so go easy on me please. See my code below

```
import pdfplumber
with pdfplumber.open('C:/Users/hasan/simsani/Invoices/Invoice SB14082021-1.pdf') as pdf:
    first_page = pdf.pages[0]
    b = first_page.extract_text()

import numpy as np
c = np.array(b, dtype = 'S')
```

When i run the script above i get an error (line 6) that says the following

> UnicodeEncode error: asci codec cannot encode character '\uf009' in position 25: ordinal not in range (128)

Is there a way to tell numpy to ignore the uf009 character and any other ones that may throw up a similar UnicodeEncode error when creating the array ?

Please give example code if you have an answer please, and make response simple (remember i am a novice here :)

Cheers

Comment: What does `np.array(b)` do?

Comment: Hello….creates a numpy array from the text in the pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can encode('ascii', 'ignore') throw a UnicodeDecodeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623476/how-can-encodeascii-ignore-throw-a-unicodedecodeerror)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no